# Cannot run feh custom action in Thunar

Tags: thunar, thunar-custom-actions

I want to open images from the Thunar file browser using feh. When I do this, I want to view the image I select as part of a filelist containing all of the images. here is the custom action I have created to approximate this behaviour:

`feh %d --start-at %f`

When I use this as the custom action in Thunar, and I try to open an image in my Pictures folder (/home/user/Pictures), I get this error message:

`Failed to execute child process "feh '/home/user/Pictures' --start-at " (No such file or directory).`

Using `feh` alone as the custom action works, but without my desired functionality.

Using `feh %f` does not work, and gives me this error message:

`Failed to execute child process "feh '/home/user/Pictures/image.png'" (No such file or directory).`

Using `"feh %f"` with quotation marks works, but without my desired functionality.

Using `"feh %d --start-at %f"` with quotation marks does not produce an error, but the file does not open.